Установила jupyter notebook, но не могу его запустить
При запросе:
pip3 show jupyter

Выдает:

Name: jupyter
Version: 1.1.1
Summary: Jupyter metapackage. Install all the Jupyter components in one go.
Home-page: https://jupyter.org
Author: Jupyter Development Team
Author-email: jupyter@googlegroups.org
License: BSD
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages
Requires: ipykernel, ipywidgets, jupyter-console, jupyterlab, nbconvert, notebook
Required-by: 

Далее ввожу:
jupyter notebook

выдает:

zsh: command not found: jupyter

Как мне его запустить?
MAC OS, Intel

Запустите как модуль python3 -m jupyter notebook

Чтобы командная оболочка zsh смогла найти jupyter,  путь к этой программе  должен быть прописан в переменной $PATH. Прописан ли он - зависит от способа установки. Если его там нет - добавьте. Как правило, он находится рядом с python, но могут быть нюансы при использовании системно установленного python и программ, установленных в среде отдельного пользователя.

Попробуйте запустить команды:
1)
python3 -m notebook




jupyter-notebook

Возможно данная ссылка поможет Вам:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313876/after-installing-with-pip-jupyter-command-not-found
